# Setting a turtle variable through Java-NetLogo-API 6

Tags: java, netlogo

I'm trying to set a turtle variable trough the Java-NetLogo-API 6.

The method I have to use for this is "setVariable(int vn, Object value)". So I need to now the exact index of the variable I want to change instead of just the variable name.
So what I do is print all the variables of a turtle in the console and then count which index number the variable I want to set is. Then I can use the method with the index number of the variable I just found out.

In the Java-NetLogo-API 4 there was a method called "setTurtleOrLinkVariable(String varName, Object value)" which just needed the name of the variable I want to set, but this method does not exist in the API 6 anymore.

So my question is if there is a better way to set a turtle variable than having to count which index number the wanted variable is to be able to change it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see you are getting help at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/netlogo-devel/RWxFgMejH6c . (it's polite to cross-link when asking the same question in multiple places, so someone doesn't waste time helping you one place, when you already got helped somewhere else)